# RegularExpression attribute with Enum

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0, data-annotations

My enums have a value of None, which means that a value has not been selected yet. None should never be saved to database.

```
enum MyEnum
{
    None = 0,
    SomeValue = 1,
...
}
```

Is there a way I can use Data annotation RegularExpression in such a way that validation should fail if None value is selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have a better chance with a `[Range(SomeValue, LastValue)]` constraint.

Comment: Range did the trick. Interesting that [RegularExpression("[1-5]")] doesn't work, seems that range was able to somehow convert value to int, while RegularExpression didn't.

Comment: You can also ensure that the value exists in the enum by adding this attribute too: `[EnumDataType(typeof(MyEnum))]` -- this might be necessary if you have gaps in your enum, such as Value1=1, Value2=2, Value3=4,Value4=8 etc. and you want to ensure that only valid enum values are used.

Comment: It seems that `RegularExpression` converts the property to string, and an enum converted to string results in its name not value, while `Range` probably does the opposite

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to do the following if all your enums define None to be 0:

```
 [RegularExpression("[1-9][0-9]*", ErrorMessage = "None should never be saved to database.")]
 public MyEnum val { get; set; }
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work, neither does [RegularExpression("[1-5]")], it seems that there is a problem with converting enum value to int. Range did work, however.